# How do I create a new column in pandas using calculated values and assign specific values to each row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df like

```
      Cards                   Height                    State Hash
0    1615427359331  ...         1945  3NK38AjJUMDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...
0    1615427359331  ...         1952  3NK38AjJUMvcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...
0    1615427359331  ...         1958  3NK38AjJUMDhEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...
0    1615427359331  ...         1952  3NK38AjJUMDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...
0    1615427359331  ...         1957  3NK38AjJUMhDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT..
```

I have calculated the value of the most occuring State hash in the dataframe and the median of height

Using these two calculated values, how can I create a New column ON/OFF.
and set the value as 1 or 0. Value 1 would be set if those two calculated values are matching else the value would be set to 0.
How do I do that using Pandas dataframe? Please help. Thanks!

**EDIT: **
This is what ive tried so far

```
if [(dataframe['Block Height'] == median_highest_blocklen_recievd) & (dataframe['State Hash'] == most_commonrec_stat_hash)]:
    dataframe['online/offline'] = 1
if [(dataframe['Block Height'] != median_highest_blocklen_recievd) | (dataframe['State Hash'] != most_commonrec_stat_hash)]:
    dataframe['online/offline'] = -1
```

and This gave me the dataframe as

```
      Cards                   Height                    State Hash   Online/Offline
                                                      
0    1615427359331  ...         1945  3NK38AjJUMDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...    -1
0    1615427359331  ...         1952  3NK38AjJUMvcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...    -1
0    1615427359331  ...         1958  3NK38AjJUMDhEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...    -1
0    1615427359331  ...         1952  3NK38AjJUMDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...    -1
0    1615427359331  ...         1957  3NK38AjJUMhDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT..    -1
```

Comment: [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), [df.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what your use case is, but you definitely want to use [numpy's where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

For example:

```
df['ON/OFF'] = np.where((df['Height']==median_height) & (df['State Hash']==mode_hash),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to do it with apply:

```
df['New'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['Height'] == median_height and x['State Hash'] == calculated_hash else 0, axis = 1)
```